# Alternatives to Journal of Computational Physics

Tags: publications

The Journal of Computational Physics has been an important outlet for computational science in the past, and I have published there before.  For the benefit of those (like me) who have signed [the Elsevier boycott](http://thecostofknowledge.com), **what non-Elsevier journals would be appropriate places to publish articles that could have been submitted to the Journal of Computational Physics?**

A good alternative should:

- Overlap (at least partially) in subject matter with JCP
- Have a good reputation
- Not be published by Elsevier

**Note**: When I say "reputation", I don't mean impact factor.  Please see [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0278) that demonstrates that the two are not well-correlated in this field.

Comment: What about code license? Do typical journals leave up to you which license your code will be under? I'm personally thinking about publishing a BSD licensed Python package and have been thinking about selection of a journal before.

Comment: @AlexE Your comment should really be posted as a new question.  The only related material I know of on this site is http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/for-software-submitted-to-acm-toms-how-does-the-acm-software-license-agreement.  You might also check academia.SE.

Most journals do not care whether your code exists, much less involve themselves in licensing it.

Comment: Done: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11437/publishing-a-software-package-along-with-a-paper-licensing

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The SIAM Journals, especially [SISC (Scientific Computing)](http://www.siam.org/journals/sisc.php) and [MMS (Multiscale Modeling and Simulation)](http://www.siam.org/journals/mms.php) are obvious established and high-quality choices.

Answer (score 9):

**Physical Review E**
http://pre.aps.org/about
Physical Review E (PRE), interdisciplinary in scope, focuses on many-body phenomena, including recent developments in quantum and classical chaos and soft matter physics. It has sections on statistical physics, equilibrium and transport properties of fluids, liquid crystals, complex fluids, polymers, chaos, **fluid dynamics**, plasma physics, classical physics, and **computational physics**. In addition, the journal features sections on two rapidly growing areas: biological physics and granular materials.

Comment: I only rarely notice papers about software packages in PRE. I think other journal may be more "typical" choices.

Answer (score 7):

I think there are several alternatives, but to some extent, it may depend upon the field. For fluid mechanics, there's obviously [*J. Fluid Mech.*](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=FLM). For many areas in microscopic physics, you could send your work to [*J. Chem. Phys.*](http://jcp.aip.org)

Answer (score 5):

Along the same lines as aeismail's answer, [International Journal of Numerical Methods in Engineering](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291097-0207/), and [International Journal of Numerical Methods in Fluids](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291097-0363) could be candidate journals for papers that would otherwise go into Journal of Computational Physics. (These journals are both Wiley journals.)

Answer (score 4):

Although not as good as SIAM journals, [Communications in Computational Physics](http://www.global-sci.com/) (CiCP) also seems promising.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [Journal of Scientific Computing](http://link.springer.com/journal/10915), which overlaps strongly with JCP in its area of focus.

Answer (score 3):

Communications in Computational Physics, published with Cambridge University Press
http://www.global-sci.com/

Journal of Computational Mathematics: free for both reader and author, published by SMAI 
http://www.euro-math-soc.eu/news/14/12/5/smai-founds-new-journal-computational-mathematics

Journal of Scientific Computing, while not Elsevier, is with Springer, still a commercial publisher.